# Is it reasonable to use a combination of two forecasting models for a dataset?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I used tbats to fit a model for a 3 years of historic data and the values work fine but as I did not include holidays, holiday predictions are really off. I used arima with regressor (holidays at regressors) and the predictions for holidays are much better than the one by tbats but tbats got more accurate results for normal days. I know it sounds un reasonable but is this ok that I use the arima model for holidays and the tbats model for normal days?

Comment: yes, its absolutely reasonable to merge two predictions from different models. In fact, I would just replace your tbats forecast  with ARIMA forecast for Holidays provided it has much accurate predictions using a hold out set. [Research](http://forprin.dev.zoe.co.nz/paperpdf/Combining.pdf)  has shown that combining forecast significantly reduces errors. Use human judgement if you have good empirical evidence as opposed to relying on computers/models to improve predictive accuracy!

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to use different models (or combine models), as long as you're sure you are not overfitting on the data (do you even have enough "holiday" data to come up with a separate model?). Still, parsimoniousness is usually preferred (at least in science), but if you notice a model does not do well on a certain part of data and you can come up with a good reason why so, and why this model would be better, then sure go ahead.

Are you sure though that this makes sense, and is not a data driven (spurious) result?

Comment: Thank you for your information. What do you mean by data driven? Im not expert in the analytic behind forecasting models, but as I have read, it is mentioned that including holidays as regressor will improve the model. Unfortunatly, the best forecasting model which can consider everything is still limited to consider regressors and it can not find a good predictions for them. On the other hand, the model which can include regressors can not consider complex seasonality. thus it is reasonable to me that each of these models can work better on different parts of the data.

Comment: With data driven I mean that you're not just choosing a model purely by "because it had a better fit statistic". I guess it is okay in your case. Are you sure you have enough holiday data points for a good prediction?

Comment: I have three years of daily data. I think I need at least 10 years of daily data to perfectly include holidays as some holidays are moving for different years and having more data can better consider them. but I dont have a 10 years of historic data